# Swift: can't use a protocol that adopts Identifiable

Tags: swift, protocols

I'm struggling to get this piece of code to work correctly:

```
protocol FileModelType: Identifiable {
    var id: ID { get set }
    var content: Data? { get set }
}

class Test: FileModelType {
    var id: Int = 0
    var content: Data? = nil
}

func test() {
    var models: [FileModelType] = [Test]()
}
```

I'm facing the famous error: `Protocol 'FileModelType' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

I need to define an array of `FileModelType` objects but don't know how to do it in this context ?

Comment: I could not imagine this implementation in a real-world example, maybe you can show us some concrete application. About your fake example, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to define an array of FileModelType objects but don't know how to do it in this context ?

It does not relate to the context. The swift language **does NOT** allow this.

You can use

```
func test() {
    var models = [Test]()
}
```

Comment: I need a way to define and use a protocol that has a unique id (regardless to its underlying type: Int, UUID, Double, etc ...) and another property with type  `Data`

Comment: @JAHelia, it is about variable `models` initialization. Declarations above remains as-is, `Test` conforms to `FileModelType`, so can be passed anywhere needed as `FileModelType`.